# i am recieving a notice in php while trying to calculate the value of a variable

Tags: php

this is php code snippet to check a form

```
<?php
include_once("includes/form_functions.php");
$var1 = 0; 
$var2 = 0; 
$var3 = 0; 
$var4 = 0; 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) // checks if submit button is clicked of form
{
    if(isset($_POST['rdvar1']))
    {
        $var5 = $_POST["rdvar1"];
        if($_POST["rdvar1"] == "RJ")
        {
            $var1 = 20;
            $var2 = 15;
        }
        else
        {
            $var1 = 5;
            $var2 = 10;
        }           
    }
    if(isset($_POST['rdvar3']))
    {
        $var3 = $_POST["rdvar3"];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['rdvar4']))
    {
        $var4 = $_POST["rdvar4"];
    }
              elseif()
    {
               // many else if validation goes here 
              } 
        else
    {
        // some more internal validations
        $var6 = $var1/100 * $var2 + $var3 * $var4; // here i calculated var6 

            if(empty($message))
            {
            // db insert query  
                  }
    }
}
?> // php tag ends

// html website starts here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

// somewhere down in html page i used

<?php
echo $var6
?>
// rest of html code and form
```

All my form code is okey, all html is good and i suppose all php i made is good too..

When i run this code there is a constant notice on the webpage

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: var6 in C:\wamp\www\aaa\calc.php on line 478
```

What i understand from undefined variable is might be local or global scope of variable... but i used this variable in the php main code and calling it again in php main code, means it isnot inside any fyunction so its scope shall be global.. still i m getting this notice, and i m not able to check what is the valule of this variable??

What could be wrong guys??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you skipped it, you only assigned on else:

```
if (condition) {
    // !! whatever here is executed
}
else
{
    // !! and this does not
    // some more internal validations
    $var6 = $var1/100 * $var2 + $var3 * $var4; // here i calculated var6 

        if(empty($message))
        { // db insert query }
}
```

The condition you put it in is not executed, you could try catching the value or improve the if condition .

To fullfil the notice and remove the error you need to init at the top of the script like the rest;

```
$var1 = 0; 
$var2 = 0; 
$var3 = 0; 
$var4 = 0; 
$var6 = 0; // <-- init this too
```

Comment: i initialized it in the begining of page as suggested by you to a zero value.. but now it is always showing zero.. no matter what option i select for var 2, 3, 4 or 1

Comment: which means that the condition you but it in, probably not logically correct. if you trying to get the value `$var6 = $var1/100 * $var2 + $var3 * $var4;`. put it outside of the `else{}` like normal assignment.

Comment: it is finally got cacluated... but on later stages of selection...

Comment: glad it worked out work you buddy. :)

Answer (score -1):

Notices are generally not overly important, and are there just to warn you about some quirks that may occur but will likely not. In this case, you can disregard the notice.

You can also disable notices by using the following PHP code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: but still, the target is output of this variable.. it shall, echo the value.. it is not doing that also... so i dont know whether or not this variable has calcualted value or not, if it is not echoing it..

Comment: Try echoing the variable on the line right after the calculation to see if it works. If it echos what you would expect, initialize the variable right after `$var4 = 0;` like this: `$var6 = 0;`

Answer (score -1):

Your code just didn't set the value of $var6. Your options are:

1. Always set $var6, like you are doing with $var1-4
2. Just hide the notice. This is done like this: <?PHP echo @$var6; ?>
3. Check if $var6 was set before you echo it: <?PHP echo isset($var6) ? $var6 : "Var6 Wasn't Set!"; ?>